# What does using (vec col) or (vector arg1 & args) cost?

Tags: clojure, list

I am working through some Lisp [exercises](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html) using Clojure. If I were to convert Lisp lists to Clojure vectors, solving some of the problems would be simpler, so here is my question:

Does using `vec` or `vector` cost a lot in terms of time and/or processing? Does using either function cause a meta state change, or are the values converted and moved to a vector?

Comment: For the most part while doing those exercises, you probably don't want to be using `vec` or `vector` but should instead prefer the generic `seq` operations. `vec` and `vector` actually build a vector which costs time and space. For example problem 1 asks you to write the `last` function. Since the core `last` function only uses the seq operations I can quickly do `(last (range 10000000))` on my machine but doing `(last (vec (range 10000000)))` waits a minute and then gives me an OutOfMemoryError

Comment: Thanks. You answered the core of my question. A new vector is created. I am also avoiding vec and vector and working with the sequence operators as you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both functions return a new vector for you.

[vec](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/vec) expect a `coll` parameter that will be converted to a vector

[vector](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/vector) expect args to create a new vector.

Bellow the excecution time for each one:

`vec`

```
user=> (time (vec '(1 2 4)))
;= "Elapsed time: 0.043 msecs"
;= [1 2 4]
```

`vector`

```
user=> (time (vector 1 2 3)))
;= "Elapsed time: 0.025 msecs"
;= [1 2 3]
```

Comment: -1: timing such short things will not yield reliable results

Answer (score 2):

I am using criterium library to measure performance.
I'm seeing better performance for vec than for apply vector

```
user=> (use 'criterium.core)
nil
user=> (def mylist (range 100))
#'user/mylist
user=> (bench (apply vector mylist))
WARNING: Final GC required 4.142753917114324 % of runtime
Evaluation count : 8356800 in 60 samples of 139280 calls.
             Execution time mean : 7.271515 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 112.366680 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 7.066423 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 7.485808 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 11.772233 ns
nil
user=> (bench (vec mylist))
Evaluation count : 8949480 in 60 samples of 149158 calls.
             Execution time mean : 6.647705 µs
    Execution time std-deviation : 83.691653 ns
   Execution time lower quantile : 6.473123 µs ( 2.5%)
   Execution time upper quantile : 6.796003 µs (97.5%)
                   Overhead used : 11.772233 ns
nil
```

Comment: Programmers is [about] conceptual questions answers are expected to explain things. Throwing code dumps instead of explanation is like copying code from IDE to whiteboard: it may look familiar and even sometimes be understandable, but it feels weird... just weird. [Whiteboard doesn't have compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5508110/839601)

Comment: I'm guessing this is a response to the other answer which attempts to make an empirical assertion about performance but uses anecdotal tools. Criterium is a fairly standard clojure microbenchmarking tool. Neither of these answers explains why there is a difference! Maybe I should provide a third... although it will be more unilluminating implementation detail.